# Why are Breadcrumbs sapui5 minimized?

Tags: sapui5

in my SAPUI5-application i use breadcrumbs. This feature is quite nice, but on a specific word ("Vertrag") the link to the overriding breadcrumb is collapsed and there's a dropdown-field. By changing the word from "Vertrag" to "Vertrags", the overriding breadcrumb isn't collapsed anymore.

Can you help me, to disaple this dropdown-field?

XML-file containing the breadcrumb:

```
<FlexBox height="50px" alignItems="Start" justifyContent="Center">
        <Breadcrumbs currentLocationText="{i18n>Contract}">
            <Link press="onPressBreadcrumb" text="{i18n>Overview}" id="Overview"/>
        </Breadcrumbs>
    </FlexBox>
```

[OK](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f3pS7.png)
[Not OK](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vGvQ9.png)

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think, this must be a issue on calculation width of the flex box. Try to play with margins, pattern or other stuff that affect rendering.

Or try to force for test like this

```
<FlexBox height="50px" alignItems="Start" justifyContent="Center">
    <Breadcrumbs currentLocationText="{i18n>Contract}">
        <Link press="onPressBreadcrumb" text="{i18n>Overview}" id="Overview"/>
    </Breadcrumbs>
    <Label text="AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA" />
</FlexBox>
```

It may be necessary to test it on all popular browsers.